# Android - Permission changed while my service is running

Tags: android, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

I have a foreground service in which i play a sound once in a while. Now i need to determine if there is an ongoing phone call to cancel my sounds. What I did is a phonestate listener, but i need a READ_PHONE_STATE permission for that and i ask for it as it is described in documentation. So, on Android M or above a user can just start the app, allow permission, then go to settings an deny it. I've tested this scenario and it causes my service to crash. So, is there any way i can detect permission change from allow to deny in a service on the runtime in a service? <strike>I've seen some guys here saying the app is restarted if a user changes permission, but this is not happening in case when only the service is running.</strike>

Edit: Thanks to CommonsWare comment i've done another check and can confirm that the foreground service also restarts if the permissions are changed.

Comment: "but this is not happening in case when only the service is running" -- are you sure? That's a bug in Android, if so.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. Thanks for making me check it again. The service does restart when permissions are changed.

Comment: Whew! Don't scare me that way! :-)

Comment: hello did you solve this problem??

Comment: there was no such issue. The service did restart and the crash was caused by smth else